# Using QR codes to locate and play a locally stored video

Tags: video, filepath

I want to use QR codes in a Gallery setting to play videos stored on tablets using QR codes. 
I do not want the QR codes to link to remote URLs but locate and play video files stored on the local memory card.
I can generate QR codes that successfully locate and launch PDFs or view jpeg files but I cannot successfully launch video files locally. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

For me, entering the following text in the qr code worked on my nexus 7 android tablet (note the three forward slashes):

```
file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/my_video.mkv
```

when I scan that barcode with the app barcode scanner and select "open browser" I can choose vlc as media player and play the video

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.  Read the data from the QR code, find the file and play it.  Did you mean to ask a specific technical question, relating to a particular language, platform, OS, framework, QR code format, etc?

Comment: Will this work in Android 4.0? What is the code and filepath I would in Android 4.0  to create a QR symbol that will launch a video file stored in its Movie folder in its Root directory.

Answer (score 0):

It's been two years+ since you asked the question and not sure have you solve the problem.  I recently solve it by generating qr code with QRCode Monkey placing the world 'video' in front of the file name.  It's strange that there should not be a space between the two (but audio reference is fine though). BUT, you have to allow the file (reside on your iPhone/device) to be shared by the QR-Jump, the scanner that jumps to ios.  Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

After a long night of trying different qr scanner apps and generators,the following setup works the best - Tested on Android 10

Get file path to your video

```
file:///yourpath/video.mp4
```

Genrate qr-code with the path from https://www.the-qrcode-generator.com/ using free text mode(Not URL).

Download Barcode Scanner+ (Plus) by sean owen.

Scan and open with any video player app.